# SQLite & LinQ Take function

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I am using SQLite (install through Nuget Package Manager). I had been trying 
to use Linq for Paging.

The error that I got: SQL logic errornear ".": syntax error'

The Sql query code at "tQuery" that I observed during debug is

{SELECT TOP (2) [t0].[R_IDs]......FROM [TTable].

The Top Keyword is not Supported in Sqllite, correct? It is suppose to be Limit and is at the end of of the Query Statement.

I had been searching around for answer.

Any one ever had this problem?

```
Table <T_Table> MyT = db.GetTable<T_Table>();
var tQuery = (from my_t in MyT 
                 select my_t).Take(5);
```

Comment: The package you are using to access SQLite doesn't properly support LINQ to SQL for SQLite. You need another driver that supports LINQ to SQLite.

Comment: Which package can I get it and Where ? Directly from SQLite Website https://www.sqlite.org/download.html?

Comment: You should be able to get `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` from nuget. That being said, there are other providers for LINQ to SQLite besides that one.

Comment: I am using the Same System.Data.SQlite.Linq. So I think the problem with the Linq are there.